# Normalize to 3NF

Tags: relational-database, normalization

```
Item_ID   Valuer   Company   value
99       Jon Lane  Lite As  3000
99       Ray dell  Hatches   3500
99       Grace Red  Webb      3000
99       Hell Sim  Chris     4000
```

I made `item_Id` and `Valuer` as the (composite)primary key.

Help on me normalizing to the 3nf. And this is no homework but something I'm working to improve my normalization skills. Found most tables easy to normalize but this one had me.

Comment: What makes you think this is not in 3NF?

Comment: How can a **single table without context** be reliably said to be NF or not?

Comment: *"I made item_Id and Valuer as the (composite)primary key."* Judging solely from the sample data, "Valuer" is a candidate key. So is "Company".

Answer (score 1):

Assessing which NF a database design is in, requires knowledge of the FDs that apply.  Where are those ?

Comment: Thanks everyone. You indirectly helped. @Oded I now think it is 3nf

Answer (score 0):

From the data given I can draft FD as below:

(item_Id,Valuer) -> (company,value)

As the (item_Id,Valuer) is PKey which is also Super key .

So it satisfied 3nf constraint that for FD X-> A 
X should be SKey.

So its in 3NF.